# How to show values array of a observable function in world map with Angular17

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, amcharts

I need some help with this. I have a world map of amChart with Angular, also I have a observable function and I can display in console the values get it of firestore, but I cannot display in the map.

```
this.countries.map((country) =>
      this.chartService
        .getNumberOfSuppliers(`organizations_${country.toLowerCase()}`)
        .subscribe((num) => {
          this.countryValue = num?.[0]?.num_org;
          // --------   BUG --------------
          // It Show values in console. The values is correct, but no is displaying in the worldchart
          // The value which taking is the default -> 0
          console.log(`${country.toLocaleUpperCase()} :`, this.countryValue); // it show the correct values
        })
    );
    this.data = this.countries.map((country) => ({
      id: country,
      name: this.getCountryName(country),
      value: this.countryValue[country], //Here I need show the values
    }));
```

```
getNumberOfSuppliers(s: string): Observable<any> {
    const chartData = collection(this.firestore, s);
    return collectionData(chartData, { idField: 'id' });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem rising is because of mishandling of code flow
try the following way

```
this.countries.map((country) =>
      this.chartService
        .getNumberOfSuppliers(`organizations_${country.toLowerCase()}`)
        .subscribe((num) => {
          this.countryValue = num?.[0]?.num_org;
          console.log(`${country.toLocaleUpperCase()} :`, this.countryValue);
          this.data = this.countries.map((country) => ({
            id: country,
            name: this.getCountryName(country),
            value: this.countryValue[country],
          }));
        })
    )
```

here as the this.data assignment will happen inside the subscribe block, ensuring that the correct values are assigned to this.countryValue before being used in this.data.

try this and let us know

Comment: I did it that but the map doesn't display.

Comment: instead of `value: this.countryValue[country]` use `value: this.countryValue` and let me know.

Comment: Sorry, the variable data must be out of the subscribe because I add the variable data in the render but it doesn't even show the default value.

Here set that data:
bubbleSeries.data.setAll(this.data);

Comment: but did you try `this.data = this.countries.map((country) => ({
  id: country,
  name: this.getCountryName(country),
  value: this.countryValue, //<--assin single value directly
}));`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't getting the desired result is because you are assigning type `Observable[]` to your `this.data`, whereas you really want the actual data shape.

First off, we should get rid of the explicit subscription inside the .map loop, because they will never be unsubscribed.  Instead of subscribing, you can "pipe" the emitted values to the shape you want.

```js
private requests = this.countries.map(country => this.chartService
    .getNumberOfSuppliers(`organizations_${country.toLowerCase()}`).pipe(
        map(num => num?.[0]?.num_org),
        map(countryValue => ({
            id    : country,
            name  : this.getCountryName(country),
            value : countryValue, 
        }))
    )
);
```

Here, we've mapped each country into an observable that will emit your desired shape (*let's call it `Data`*).  So `requests` is type `Observable<Data>[]`.

We can use [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) to subscribe to an array of observables and emit their results as an array.

```js
private sub = forkJoin(this.requests).subscribe(
   data => this.data = data // here data is Data[]
);

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

---

Instead of stashing the result of the `.subscribe()` in a separate variable, you could just keep it as observable and use `async` pipe in the template.  This is simpler because you no longer need to handle unsubscribing:

```js
public data$ = forkJoin(this.requests);
```

```html
<!-- This is just for displaying the data in the template-->
<pre>
  {{ data$ | async | json }}
</pre>

<!-- But you'd probably just pass it as an input to some component -->
<some-component [input]="data$ | async" />
```

Comment: Hi, at the moment I cannot do it work. The values I don't show it in the template.